# why do I get an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' while doing language translation using googletrans?

Tags: python

While trying to translate  any language to English using googletrans I am getting an error stating "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group"

Below is the code for reference:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
translator = Translator()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Spanish':['piso','cama']})
df

df['English'] = df['Spanish'].apply(translator.translate, 
                                    src='es', dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
```

Comment: restart your kernal, it can works fine for me

Comment: It's not your code.
I get exactly the same error with this simple example from the documentation.
`translator.translate('veritas lux mea', src='la')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to a bug in version 3.0.0. To make it work, you can either upgrade to the latest pre-release version **4.0.0rc1**:

```
pip install --upgrade googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

or use another library such as **[google_trans_new](https://pypi.org/project/google-trans-new/)**:

```
pip install google-trans-new
```